# How to reschedule a coordinator job in OOZIE without restarting the job?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

When i changed the start time of a coordinator job in job.properties in oozie, the job is not taking the changed time, instead its running in the old scheduled time.

Old job.properties:

```
startMinute=08
startTime=${startDate}T${startHour}:${startMinute}Z
```

New job.properties:

```
startMinute=07
startTime=${startDate}T${startHour}:${startMinute}Z
```

The job is not running at the changed time:07th minute,its running at 08th minute in every hour.

Please can you let me know the solution, how i can make the job pickup the updated properties(changed timing) without restarting or killing the job.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really change the timing of the co-ordinator via any methods given by Oozie(v3.3.2) . When you submit a job the contents properties are stored in the database whereas the actual workflow is in the HDFS.

Everytime you execute the co-ordinator it is necessary to have the workflow in the **path** specified in properties during job submission but the properties file is not needed. What I mean to imply is the properties file does not come into the picture after submitting the job.

One hack is to update the time directly in the database using SQL query.But I am not sure about the implications of it.The property might become inconsistent across the database.

You have to kill the job and resubmit a new one.

**Note**: oozie provides a way to change the concurrency,endtime and pausetime [as specified in the official docs](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Changing_endtimeconcurrencypausetime_of_a_Coordinator_Job).